# How do I add permission to read on a drive

Tags: windows-8, file-permissions

I have badly messed up my hard drive permissions.

I was trying to deny guest accounts from accessing one of my logical partitions. While disabling the read, write permissions I have disabled read permission of everyone.

Now one of my drive is not accessible.

I tried changing the properties back but it needs read permission to do so. Hence, I couldn't reset.

I went through another question and tried
icacls F: /t  /grant Everyone:FF. I am getting access denied error message.

I formatted my C drive hoping the meta deta would be deleted. While formatting I tried icacls command to give read permission but I was getting access denied.

Please help in resolving this issue.

---

**UPDATE**

1. I formatted the C drive which had my Windows OS. I did not format the partition which is having a lot of valuable data - Years of work will be lost. Formatting would be worst option for me.
2. I am using icacls command on the drive which has no read/write permission.
3. I Went to Properties of F drive, Under security, I choose the groups and I checked deny on full control. With reflex I clicked on ok rather than cancel. Messed pretty bad.

---

*Update-2*
[image: Drive -> Properties -> Security]

[image: On clicking advance]

Comment: This is unclear: (1) Do you mean that reformatting the partition didn't reset its permissions? (2) Why do you need to use icacls on a newly formatted volume? (3) And how have you "disabled read permission of everyone"? - Please give details so we could better understand the problem.

Comment: @harrymc : Give me a minute.. I will update the details. :)

Comment: Does it work if you `takeown` before `icacls`? http://www.faqforge.com/windows/take-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder-by-command-in-windows/

Comment: @IvanKozik : I have to try it..

Comment: @harrymc : Thanks for asking the questions.. I hope my question is more clear.

Comment: @NewUser, How did you run takeown or icacls ? If you just used command prompt, try with "run as administrator" option.

Comment: @Kumar : don't remember the result of takeown. icacls is give error message saying F: Access is denied.

Comment: Have a look at the very detailed procedure described in [this thread](http://superuser.com/a/837876/8672), where `takeown` and `icacls` are used, but the difference is that they are used via logon to the real Administrator account which is normally disabled. If this works for you, I will summarize the procedure in an answer.

Comment: Try to use the [local system account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. It is a powerful account that has unrestricted access to all local system resources. You can use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to login to that account in a command prompt. The command to do that would be `psexec -s cmd` (in [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html)). From there try to change permissions.

Comment: Years of work and no backups during that time? How did you expect to make it *this* far without the drive failing or somesuch?

Comment: @JDługosz : Reminds me "Why do we fall, Bruce". So that we can start taking backup of important data. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is an tricky option to get your data, But it won't fix your problem without format.

1. Download and Write Ubuntu live disk to DVD or to your USB.
2. Boot Ubuntu and choose use without installation.
3. On left side bar, your drive will be show, just click it and it'll mount automatically.
4. Copy your data to another partition.
5. Format your problematic partition and reuse it.

**Note 1**: If auto mount not works, try by following link

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

**Note 2**: You can use [Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), this is based on Mini Windows XP. There is a chance to get data without much work. But not sure.

**Hint**: I'm not sure whether it'll work or not, change your drive letter by disk management. Just try.

Comment: Already tried Changing drive letter doesn't work :D

Answer (score 2):

The procedure below is a rewrite of an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/837876/8672) from the thread
[Reset File and Folder Permission of External Hard Drive Data to default in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/659787/reset-file-and-folder-permission-of-external-hard-drive-data-to-default-in-windo/837876#837876) :

1. [Enable the Built-in Administrator Account](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html), which is disabled by default,
   and [assign a password](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/7666-password-create-user-account-windows-8-a.html).
2. Login as the Administrator to the computer.
3. Run the Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator and enter the following commands.
4. Take ownership of all folders under drive X using [TAKEOWN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) :
   `TAKEOWN /F X:\ /R /D Y`
5. Assign all permissions using [ICACLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) :
   `ICACLS X:\ /reset /T`
6. Verify that the disk in question is now accessible.
7. Logoff the Administrator, logon as your usual user, and disable again
   the built-in Administrator account, as described in the above link.

If this does not work, try it also while [Booting Into Safe Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/).

You could also try the free [AccessGain](http://www.hobeanu.com/accessgain/) (with which I have no personal experience) :

> AccessGain helps you access and recover information from hard drives
>   or previous Windows installations without having to struggle with NTFS
>   security permissions (taking ownership and waiting forever).

If nothing works, then I suggest to try and save your data, then reformat the drive.

See the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm)
for a list of recovery programs. Some of them will access your drive through direct
and physical disk access rather than via NTFS,
therefore bypassing the permissions problem.

The last time I have tried them, [MiniTool Power Data Recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/) gave the best
results. The [free version](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/power-data-recovery.html) is limited in the amount of data it will save
and the full version costs $69.
However, as the folder structure is healthy, since the problem is just with
permissions, other products recommended in the article might work for you.

Comment: Getting Access denied error..

Comment: Do you get it on the TAKEOWN command or ICACLS? Try to redo this procedure as Administrator but [in Safe boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/).

Comment: I have added more info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. First solution:

   You can try this: open your command prompt as administrator and type explorer.
   It will open explorer then edit the permission(This would solve the permission denied error.)
2. Second Solution:
    Mount your drive in other operating system like linux or MacOS.

Comment: First option is not feasible, I have removed read permission as well. Hence I don't have permission to view the permissions as we..

Comment: Then mount it in other OS or in other machine in same OS and try change the permission on that drive.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your disk to another system, copy the content, format it, prepare for restore and restore, in my experience this is much faster way to rollback to previous state.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue in my Windows 10 (although not with a root directory, only a normal directory - I did not have a spare hard disk to lose...)

When I try to access the security of that directory, I get the same error. However, the 'Change Owner' button *is* available, and I *can* change the owner to 'Admin'. There is an error message when saving that I am not authorized, but the owner *does* get changed to 'Admin', and then I can - as the user with that ID - change the rights even though it sits on all 'DENY'.

According to the warning that comes when I create the situation, *the owner can always change the rights* even if he is explicitly denied so. And as an admin, you can always change the owner.

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (first result of google search for 'reset ntfs acls':

http://lallouslab.net/2013/08/26/resetting-ntfs-files-permission-in-windows-graphical-utility/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved if you are logged in Windows as an administrator. See the 'change' link in your Update-2 picture?, click it to change the owner of the drive to you. Then you can re-assign the permissions to the users including you. Remember the check the 'Replace all child object....' checkbox as well.