# windows 10, how to access files from system partition when hd connected externally

Tags: windows-10

The problem i am having is that my desktop computer got broken and i was using it in my company, i have on it clients database and all sorts of legal documents. I was happy to learn that hard drive is alright when i connected it using external sata pocket.

Hard drive was divided on 2 partitions, system (C) and data (D), nothing special. I can freely access data from D:, but when i open C: i dont see anything. I remember having similiar problem in the past with previous versions of windows.

Does someone know if there is a way to unlock the data so i can copy it safely? I didnt have any password on my windows account and there was only 1 account on it (created while installing windows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset File and Folder Permission of External Hard Drive Data to default in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/659787/reset-file-and-folder-permission-of-external-hard-drive-data-to-default-in-windo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason all your documents got hidden and maybe even the permissions all changed.

Open Command Prompt as administrator and type the following :

> **cacls c: /t /e /c /g Everyone:f**

If your drive is something other than C drive replace c: with your current drive.

After that, type this in :

> **attrib -s -h /s /d**

You can open command Prompt by going to Start > Type *cmd* > Right click *Run as Adminstrator*

Comment: i understand that i need to change "c:" with current partition letter ? when i conncted this hard drive externally to my notebook it doesnt have letter "C" anymore.

Comment: @P.K. Correct. I assumed that C: would be the drive since you were mentioned C: and D: in your question.